# Instead of random, it generates sequence of numbers

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, random

I want to generate x number of random numbers and everything works except it gives me sequenced numbers, not random numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){

int x;
printf("How many  elements do you want?\n");
scanf("%d", &x);
int *array = (int *)malloc(x * sizeof(int));
srand(time(NULL));
for(int y = 0; y < x; y++){

    *(array + y) = 2 +  rand() % 99;
}

for(int y = 0; y <x; y++){
    printf("Array element %d: %d\n", y, (*array+ y));

}

return 0;}
```

It gives the numbers like:  27 28 29 30 31, only the first number is random in each execution, others are sequential.

Comment: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: `*(array + y)` and `(*array + y)` are not the same. If you'd used the common notation `array[y]` this nasty typo probably would not have happened.

Comment: Note that for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. The latter is generally easier to read, less to write, and also safe from errors like the one you have.

Comment: `*(pointer + integer)` is 100% absolutely the same as `pointer[integer]`. Note that using an array identifier in these kind of expressions implicitly converts from array type to pointer type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely you're printing a wrong value.

You need to change `(*array+ y)` to `*(array+ y)` in `printf()` statement, otherwise, you end up printing the value of the first random number, plus the iteration counter (which explains the output you get).

*Just to add some opinionated view:* The array indexing operator `[]` is there, some chose to prefer using it to avoid mistakes just like this. Your statements can be easily re-written to make use of that, like

```
for(int y = 0; y < x; y++){

    array[y] = 2 +  rand() % 99;
}

for(int y = 0; y <x; y++){
    printf("Array element %d: %d\n", y, array[y]);
}
```

That said,

- Please see [do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)
- Always check for the success of the called function before using the return value. Check against `NULL`  return of the `malloc()` call, otherwise you may end up dereferencing `NULL`, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)